# IndexOutOfBoundException with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, linearlayoutmanager

I am experiencing a problem with my application. I am getting a **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder** and not only on Samsung device but also on LG because I have read somewhere that this exception only happens on Samsung device.

My solution was to make my own `LinerLayoutManager` and to catch the exception in `onLayoutChildren()` method. After implementing this solution the exception doesn't occur very often like before but still sometimes ocurrs when I close the app and start it again immediately after closing.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Here is my `LinearLayoutManager`:

```
 public class WrapContentLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {


  public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
 }

  public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,    int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    try {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        Timber.e("catching recycler view IndexOutOfBoundsException = " + e);
     }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
     return false;
 }
}
```

and in the `MainFragment`:

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{27dd5184 position=1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5041)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5172)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1225)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1045)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4579)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: please post your code with error log

Comment: @ApurvaKolapkar  I've edited the question with the code and error log

Comment: Did your problem become solve? i also have same problem

Comment: Help please same issue

Comment: yeah, question still good even in 2020 - trying to handle this kind of exception.

Comment: Still good in 2021 too.

Comment: is there any solution?